# Sending GridView into edit mode with the use of a separate button

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, webforms, inline-editing

I've used `GridView.EditIndex = -1` to do this, however I always have to click the button twice. If data is already present in the gridview, it is removed from the gridview. Why is this?

I have tried:
    `this.subBindGrid();`

```
protected void subBindGrid()
{
    GridView.Columns[7].Visible = true;
    GridView.DataSource = <filepath>.Tables[0].DefaultView;
    GridView.DataBind();
}
```

I have also tried:

```
GridView.DataBind();
```

on it's own.

Neither of these have made any difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever you click on any control on a page. Than request is sent to the server for new page due to stateless nature of http. Every time you click on button you get a new page with `DataSource` of gridview is empty. to solve this. after `GridView.EditIndex = -1`.
Bind your Datasource and `subBindGrid();` remember this will work only if `<filepath>.Tables[0].DefaultView` is not null

Comment: Ok, I have a data adaptor `holdone` and dataset `holdall`. How do I give `holdall` some persistence, so that the `DefaultView` that points at it does not return null?

Comment: you can use session for state management. make default view of your table and store it in session use it whenever you need. But if you want to get updated data every time than you must fill your datatable from database.